# How can i get text from br tag using JAVA and SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i need some help and i want to understand the method.

I have to make assertion for new address that i've just created on website.

The html looks like this

```
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          
  <article id="address-30338" class="address" data-id-address="30338">
    <div class="address-body">
      <h4>Piotr</h4>
      <address>Piotr Testowy<br>Woronicza<br>10-123<br>Warszawa<br>United Kingdom<br>533243444</address>
            
    </div>
```

I need to getText from br Woronicza - like addressData 
I need to getText from br 10-123    - like zipCodeData 
etc...

When i use 
WebElement aliasData = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#content > div:nth-child(3) h4")); 
assertEquals(alias, aliasData.getText());

It works fine but form br tag i have no idea how to make it right using Selenium and Java.

I dont know what should be a correct xpath or maybe in this example i should use other selector ?

When i am trying using this code - selenium reports that string is empty and it is no equal to Woronicza.

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[2]//h4/following-sibling::address/br"));

        String addressData = elements.get(1).getText();
        String zipCodeData = elements.get(2).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        String cityData = elements.get(3).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        String countryData = elements.get(4).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        String phoneData = elements.get(5).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the inner text from your  tag as a sring and just split the text with using the 
 tag as delimiter.

```
String[] data = dataFromSeleniumAsString.split("<br>");
String name = data[0];
String city = data[1];
...
```